# Rack and trusted IPs

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm not a Rack expert, so I didn't understand one thing that appeared on [Rack 1.4 source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L315):

```
def trusted_proxy?(ip)
  ip =~ /^127\.0\.0\.1$|^(10|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)|192\.168)\.|^::1$|^fd[0-9a-f]{2}:.+|^localhost$/i
end

def ip
  remote_addrs = @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] ? @env['REMOTE_ADDR'].split(/[,\s]+/) : []
  remote_addrs.reject! { |addr| trusted_proxy?(addr) }

  return remote_addrs.first if remote_addrs.any?

  forwarded_ips = @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ? @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].strip.split(/[,\s]+/) : []

  if client_ip = @env['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
    # If forwarded_ips doesn't include the client_ip, it might be an
    # ip spoofing attempt, so we ignore HTTP_CLIENT_IP
    return client_ip if forwarded_ips.include?(client_ip)
  end

  return forwarded_ips.reject { |ip| trusted_proxy?(ip) }.last || @env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
end
```

```

`trusted_proxy?`seems to return if the address belongs to a local network (or even my own computer).

Does it rejects `trusted_ips` with `forwarded_ips` because it seems that I'm forging an IP doing a request from outside when I'm inside a network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trusted_proxy?` returns true if it's trusted, and yes, it appears that it only returns true if it's a local address - something with 10.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x, the loopback address (127.0.0.1), or `localhost`, etc.

Below that, it has `remote_addrs.reject!` which takes a collection, and removes from that collection anything that is `true` in the block. Imagine you have a collection of IP addresses (a mix of local and remote) - what that block does is take that list of IP addresses and **rejects** any that return true through the `trusted_proxy?` method, therefore all you have left over are the remote addresses.

To say it another way, it takes a list of IP addresses and rejects the local ones, leaving you with only remote IPs.

The `forwarded_ips` are picked up based on the info in the header, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, etc.

Finally, the block that starts with `if client_ip` returns `true` if the list of `forwarded_ips` includes the `client_ip`, and `false` otherwise.

Overall, and I'm guessing a bit on this last part, but I think the purpose of the `ip` method is to ultimately return the IP address of the connection, or something, if and only if it's a trusted IP that doesn't otherwise appear to be a spoofing attempt. Like I said I'm  not really sure on that, but the `ip` method appears to be acting as a series of filters on the input to give you back something useful within the scope of the purpose of that method.